# jQuery: event listener not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add an event listener to a html element using Jquery.

**test.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>

  <body>
      <select id="options" >                                                                                                                   
         <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>                                                                                                  
         <option value="saab">Saab</option>
         <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
         <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
  </body>
```

**test.js**

```
alert("outside function");
$('#options').change(function() {

    alert("inside function");
    var x = $('#options option:selected').text();
    alert(x);
});
```

Now when I open `file:///home/ronnie/check/popup.html` and if I select anyone of the options my jquery function doesn't get triggered and I just get `outside function` popup.

I tried the same code in jsfiddle and it works absolutely fine http://jsfiddle.net/Vj9LK/.

So, my question is why it is not working in chromium.

Comment: it works fine in my chrome

Answer (score 4):

You're selecting `$("#options")` in `test.js`, which is defined in the `<script>` tag before the `<body>` is constructed. jQuery has a function to wait until everything is constructed, so that you can select elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // contents of test.js
});
```

Comment: This is probably the cause (so your answer is a solution). Actually, jQuery has a shortcut for what you have written: `$(function(){ ... });` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`.

Answer (score 3):

have you put the change function within document(ready)?

Try this

```
alert("outside function");

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#options').change(function() {
        alert("inside function");
        var x = $('#options option:selected').text();
        alert(x);
    });
});
```

Comment: @roXon: MattG answered the question 5 second after first person, I suppose your comment is pointless here.

Answer (score 3):

The DOM is not loaded yet. You need to use `.ready` function - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
alert("outside function");
$(function(){
  $('#options').change(function() {

    alert("inside function");
    var x = $('#options option:selected').text();
    alert(x);
  });
});
```

Comment: @roXon: Take a look at timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

put your code in $(document).ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("outside function");
    $('#options').change(function() {

        alert("inside function");
        var x = $('#options option:selected').text();
        alert(x);
    });
})
```

Comment: sorry till the time i was typing others posted their answers, and i didnt get any update about it.

Comment: @AmitKhanna: Because it happened very quickly. Can't judge person answering the question only because he/she was couple seconds after the first person answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason could be this:

When you do `<script src="test.js"></script>` in your html file, you haven't defined the `options` select tag yet, thus the onchange function is not getting registered properly. So try it after you define the `select` tag.

Or choose `$(document).ready(function(){})` which gives you desired result.

Answer (score 0):

use this code its working, be sure always write   after

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <select id="options" >                                                                                                                   
             <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>                                                                                                  
             <option value="saab">Saab</option>
             <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
             <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          </select>
     <script>
       $('#options').change(function() {

        alert("inside function");
        var x = $('#options option:selected').text();
        alert(x);
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```